# xsl Template match

Tags: xml, xslt

I am creating xml using xsl with xml

Here is the code for XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<example>
<sample>245 34</sample>
<sample1>24 36</sample1>
</example>
```

With the help of XSL I want to split the xml value

When i am checking in google i saw there is a method we can use substring-before or substring-after(query)

but i am little confused how to bring the values like below

```
<example>
<text>245</text>
<text>34</text
<text>24</text>
<text>36</text>
</example>
```

Could any one help me how to bring the value as above

Thanks 
m

Comment: maha, Can you use XSLT 2.0 or are you confined only to XSLT 1.0? Are there only two numbers in a sample or can they be many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing in this situation is to split on the space delimiter. If you're restricted to XSLT 1.0 the simplest way of doing this is via the EXSLT library (this is available by default in many XSLT implementations, e.g. PHP's).

You can run the below at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/B0POKh) (see output **source**).

```
<!-- root -->
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <example>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='*' />
    </example>
</xsl:template>

<!-- match sample nodes -->
<xsl:template match="example/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select='str:split(., " ")' />
</xsl:template>

<!-- match token nodes (from EXSLT split()) -->
<xsl:template match='token'>
    <text><xsl:value-of select='.' /></text>
</xsl:template>
```

As shown in the playground, to use EXSLT (provided it's available to you) you need to declare its namespace in your opening `xsl:stylesheet` tag. For example to use its strings library (as we do here, to utilise `split()`), you'd put:

```
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str"
```

**[EDIT]** - if you insist on a **substring approach**, this is possible but more long-winded because, without the ability to generate a node set (which is what EXSLT's `split()` does) and, therefore, apply templates on that node set, the only trick you have in your bag is recursion - one template calling itself for as many times as a space features in it.

You can run this at [this (separate) XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/QAG203)

```
<!-- root child nodes -->
<xsl:template match='example/*'>
    <xsl:call-template name='output'>
        <xsl:with-param name='source' select='.' />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>


<!-- output - expects two params: -->
<!-- @output_str - the sub-string to output to a <text> node this time (has value only on self-call, i.e. recursion -->
<!-- @source - the source string on which to recurse, for more spaces in the string -->

<xsl:template name='output'>

    <xsl:param name='output_str' />
    <xsl:param name='source' />

    <!-- output something this time? -->
    <xsl:if test='$output_str'>
        <text><xsl:value-of select='$output_str' /></text>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- recurse... -->
    <xsl:if test='$source'>
        <xsl:choose>

            <!-- $source contains spaces - act on the string before the next space -->
            <xsl:when test='contains($source, " ")'>
                <xsl:call-template name='output'>
                    <xsl:with-param name='output_str' select='substring-before($source, " ")' />
                    <xsl:with-param name='source' select='substring-after($source, " ")' />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- source doesn't contain spaces - act on it in its entirety -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name='output'>
                    <xsl:with-param name='output_str' select='$source' />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: hi @Utkanos thanks for the reply but instead split function i want to do in substring  is that possible can you help me out that

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide a solution via this approach, also.

Comment: hi @Utkanos this is what i want. :)

Is that possible can we have something like the below output instead of displaying the numbers

my expecting output was for the above question 

<text>254</text>
<text>34</text>

is that possible can we give like this

Comment: This is what happens - see the output SOURCE (click 'view source' tab), as it generates XML.

Comment: hi @Utkanos right now we are getting the value as <text>254</text><text>54</text>

but still what i want is <text>254</text><text1>54</text1>

please help me how to do this thank you very much

Comment: hi @Utkanos can you pls tell me how to get the output as the above comment

Comment: Er, with quite a bit of difficulty.

Comment: hi @Utkanos I have got the solution thank you very much. I have posted one more query can you able to help out that please.